# jQuery not getting the select Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and calling a modal like this:

```
$('.editResp').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({url:"modal/db.edit.modal.resp.php?id="+id,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $(".modal-content").html(result);
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }});
});
```

On the modal I have a select box:

```
<select id="responsiblelist" title="Select Responsible" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-style="btn-primary" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%">
<option value="1">Test</option>
<option value="2">Test</option>
</select>
```

And the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="SaveResp()">Save</button>
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SaveResp() {
    var username = $('#responsiblelist').val();
    console.log(username);
}
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click the button the console logs an empty string. I think somehow this is due to the modal content being added dinamically.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**
Code corrected.

Comment: i assume you have written the option tags as `<option>` in your code?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes I did, just corrected it.

Comment: Should work.. make sure that you don't have more than one element with the id `responsiblelist` in your document.